# Is there a way to improve this Javascript Regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to clean-up a windows folder path using the following Javascript.

```
    function StandardizeFolderPath(inFolderPath) {
        var outFolderPath = inFolderPath.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        outFolderPath = outFolderPath.replace(/\\\s*/g, "\\");
        outFolderPath = outFolderPath.replace(/\s*\\/g, "\\");
        outFolderPath = outFolderPath.replace(/\\{2,}/, "\\");

        alert("^" + inFolderPath + "$           " + "^" + outFolderPath + "$");

        return outFolderPath;
    }

    function Test_StandardizeFolderPath() {
        StandardizeFolderPath("D:\\hel   xo  \\");
        StandardizeFolderPath("D:\\hello  \\        ");
        StandardizeFolderPath("D:\\hello  \\        \\");
        StandardizeFolderPath("D:\\hello  \\        mike \\");
        StandardizeFolderPath("  D:\\hello  \\        jack \\");
        StandardizeFolderPath("  D:\\hello Multiple Slashes \\\\");
    }
```

Each replace does specific parts:

1. Remove spaces from fron and back
2. Replace any `"\  "` with `"\"`
3. Replace any `"  \"`
4. Replace multiple occurrences of `"\"` with a single.

It gets the job done, but I want to know if there is a better way (with explanation)

Comment: You don't have any test case for the 4.

Comment: @dystroy 4th gets tested with this statement "D:\\hello  \\        \\"

Comment: Partially only. There could be no space in between. But you know what can occur in the real cases, I was just pointing this omission relative to your rules.

Comment: @dystroy Thanks for pointing that out.  Does the code that you provided below also solve that.

Comment: Y U NO .trim() for #1 replace?

Comment: Where does a Windows folder printout ever get in this condition?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Working with an older version so no trim().  I am modifying some very old ASP code.  Trim was my first choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merge three of your replacements :

```
function StandardizeFolderPath(inFolderPath) {
    return inFolderPath.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").replace(/(\s*\\\s*)+/g, "\\");
}
```

Here's what `/(\s*\\\s*)+/g` means :

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/                        start of regex literal
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \1 . The + makes it work for one or
                           more occurences
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/                         end of regex literal
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
g                         executes more than once
```

References :

- [regex explainer](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%5Cs%2a%5C%5C%5Cs%2a%29%2b)
- [The MDN on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Well... not the first one that I've left untouched.

Comment: You're missing the `{2,}` from the fourth one.

Comment: @PeterBoughton No, I don't. There's the + for that. It also takes care of "\\\\" or "\\  \\".

Comment: @dystroy Thanks that does help.  Could you please add a little explanation to your answer so that I can understand better.  Significance of "/" at the beginning and "/g" at the end.  Also how the "()+" works.

Comment: @PranavShah I detailed and added some links you should read to get a better understanding

Comment: @dystroy  Is it correct to assume that at least 2 Replace will be required to solve this problem?

Comment: @PranavShah It's probably possible to do it with one but it will be harder to maintain and test.

Comment: Since we don't need group values, I suggest write it as `/(?:\s*\\\s*)+/g`

Comment: @Yousui Yes but why ? Is there a real gain in execution ?

Comment: Oh, I missed that grouping... but unless I'm being doubley dense, it's redundant anyhow - `/x/g` will do the same as `/(x)+/g` does, except in the latter JS may or not optimize away the unnecessary capturing group. Whether there's any significant difference between `/\s*\\\s*/g` and `/\s*\\{2,}\s*/g` will depend on the inputs (I suspect doubled backslashes without spaces is more common than with), as well as where this is being used (i.e. single user on user input vs inside a nested loop).

Comment: Compact and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

A single regular expression

```
s.replace(/ *(\\)(\\? *)+|^ *| *$/g, "$1")
```

seems to do the trick.

The idea is that of a block made up with spaces followed by a backslash followed by a sequence of other backslashes or spaces you want to keep only the backslash.

The other cases are for removing initial and ending spaces.

Comment: I don't think it works for now. Try `"\\ a"`. It can be fixed of course but I find this hard to maintain and check.

Comment: @dystroy: true, I don't see how to do everything with just one pass without look-behind zero-width assertions that are not supported everywhere. Added a second pass.

Comment: In fact I think that those assertions are supported in no browser.

Comment: @dystroy: while dining I got the idea that using a capturing group could make it... seems it works.